# If I always return 0 in Comparator.compare() why do I end-up with 1 item in my Set?

Tags: java, collections

I wrote a custom Comparator for a TreeSet. To debug, I decided to hardwire "compare()" to always return 0. To my surprise, one item is entered into the Set.

Why would that be? I'm doing my best to understand the relationship between "set.add()" and "compare()".

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why?

Comment: well. if i insert. and compare() says it is already equal to something, then it should prevent the insertion (i thought).

Comment: Already equal to _what_? What do you think it's comparing to?

Comment: So... add(); before add() can happen, compare() must be consulted; compare() returns 0 and says "nope. that value already exists in the set".  So, if compare() is hardwired to always answer "nope. already in the set", how does anything ever get added?

Comment: Completely wrong.  If the set is empty, `compare()` is never called, because an empty set cannot contain anything.

Comment: @SLaks I don't know what to say. I have a TreeSet with a custom Comparator. I put one item in the TreeSet, compare() fires, compare() returns 0, and yet one item is put in the TreeSet. I genuinely appreciate your answer. I've spent hours on the Comparator, but at this point I need to use a different collection. thanks.

Comment: `compare()` will not be called if there are no items to compare to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always returning zero means that all items are equal to all other items.

That will not prevent you from adding the single possible item.

Comment: So, a return value of zero can mean 1 of 2 things. The objects being compared are equal. Or, returning zero could also mean, the set was empty before compare() was invoked. So, even with a return of 0, an insertion still happens.

Comment: No.  You're completely misunderstanding `compare()`.  `compare()` just compares **two** items.  If the set is empty, there is nothing to compare to.